# How to create a list (an arrary) of mappings (an associative sub-array) in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7, mapping

I am a n00b to Python and am attempting to bring the little bit of knowledge I have from shell and PHP scripting to Python. I really trying to grasp the concepts of creating and manipulating the values within (while keeping the code in an understandable form).

I am having trouble utilizing the Python implementations of LISTS and MAPPINGS ( dict() ). I am writing a script that needs to use an associative array (a python mapping) inside of a basic array (a Python list). The list can use the typical INT index.

Thanks!

Here is what I have currently:

```
'''  Marrying old-school array concepts
[in Python verbiage] a list (arr1) of mappings (arr2)
[per my old-school training] a 2D array with 
        arr1 using an INT index
        arr2 using an associative index
'''
arr1 = []
arr1[0] = dict([    ('ticker'," "),
                        ('t_date'," "),
                        ('t_open'," "),
                        ('t_high'," "),
                        ('t_low'," "),
                        ('t_close'," "),
                        ('t_volume'," ")
                        ] )
arr1[1] = dict([    ('ticker'," "),
                        ('t_date'," "),
                        ('t_open'," "),
                        ('t_high'," "),
                        ('t_low'," "),
                        ('t_close'," "),
                        ('t_volume'," ")
                        ] )

arr1[0]['t_volume'] = 11250000
arr1[1]['t_volume'] = 11260000

print "\nAssociative array inside of an INT indexed array:"
print arr1[0]['t_volume'], arr1[1]['t_volume']
```

In PHP, I have the following example working:

```
'''
arr_desired[0] = array( 'ticker'        => 'ibm'
                            't_date'        => '1/1/2008'
                            't_open'        => 123.20
                            't_high'        => 123.20
                            't_low'     => 123.20
                            't_close'   => 123.20
                            't_volume'  => 11250000
                        );
arr_desired[1] = array( 'ticker'        => 'ibm'
                            't_date'        => '1/2/2008'
                            't_open'        => 124.20
                            't_high'        => 124.20
                            't_low'     => 124.20
                            't_close'   => 124.20
                            't_volume'  => 11260000
                        );

print arr_desired[0]['t_volume'],arr_desired[1]['t_volume'] # should print>>> 11250000 11260000
'''
```

Comment: if you already know some programming language; give [python tutorial a try](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list and dict literal definitions can be much simplified:

```
keys = ['ticker', 't_date', 't_open', 't_high', 't_low', 't_close', 't_volume']
arr1 = [
    dict.fromkeys(keys, ' '),
    dict.fromkeys(keys, ' ')
]
```

I'm using the [`dict.fromkeys()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.fromkeys) method to initialize a dict with a sequence of keys, all with a given default value (a one-space string).

When you define an empty list in Python, you cannot simply address elements that don't exist. Alternatively, use the `.append()` method to add *new* elements to a list:

```
arr1.append({'key': 'value', 'otherkey': 'othervalue'})
```

The above example uses the `{k: v}` dict literal notation.

I suspect you would benefit from reading the (excellent) [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) first.

Comment: Thank you!    <pre><code>The dict.fromkeys(keys,' ')</code></pre> logic works well, along with the append() logic.  Yes, I was using the tutorial and got but so far before having to ask my question.  From what I can tell, the tutorial is very good. However, it can only get a person so far (i.e. - your logic is not covered). Again, thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I learned, for those coming from a similar programming background as mine:

```
arr0 = dict( [ ('one',1), ('two',2), ('three',3) ] )
for k,v in arr0.iteritems() : 
    print k,v           #prints the associative array key with the value

keys = ['ticker','t_open','t_high','t_low','t_close','t_volume']
arr1 = [
            dict.fromkeys(keys,' '),
            dict.fromkeys(keys,' ')
        ]

arr1[0]['t_volume'] = 11250000
arr1[1]['t_volume'] = 11260000
arr1.append( {'ticker' : 'ibm', 't_date' : '1/2/2008', 't_volume' : 11270000} )
arr1.insert(3, {'ticker' : 'ibm', 't_date' : '1/3/2008', 't_volume' : 11280000} )

print "\nAssociative array inside of an INT indexed array:"
print arr1[0]['t_volume'], arr1[1]['t_volume']
print "\n ",arr1[2]
print arr1[2]['t_volume'], arr1[3]['t_volume']
```

Note the element(value) addition logic.

Comment: Don't create a literal dict with a sequence of tuples, the syntax is needlessly verbose.

Comment: Now that I have spent some time on this, I definitely agree with your position of not using a sequence of tuples. However, the [Python Tutorial on Dictionaries][tutorial]:http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries uses tuples as an example. Just providing stepping stones for other in the future.

Comment: You could use: `{'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}` or if all keys are valid python identifiers: `dict(one=1, two=2, three=3)`.